# Need help centering my text below my image when resolution changes

Tags: css

I am trying to make a responsive website. I am trying so if the resolution changes my text will stay under my photo. (for example, if someone resizes their web browser.) My first question, if the format is wrong I apologize. Thank you for taking the time to read and help! (note I only added the HTML and CSS that targets this problem if all code is needed I can post a GitHub link.)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="Mid">
    <div id="TopLeft">
        Daniel Apacik
    </div>
    <div id="Selfie">
        <img src="images/me.jpg" alt="Photo of Daniel Apacik">
    </div>
    <div id="About">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto pariatur atque excepturi id vero voluptatibus iste commodi. Necessitatibus atque illo itaque officia exercitationem maiores culpa molestiae ipsa. Voluptates, iste magni.
    </div>
    <div id="TopRight">
        Projects | Contact 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.Mid {
background: url(images/midback2.png) center;
background-size: cover;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-width: 1000px;
min-height: 1000px;
font-size: 16px; 
height: 2em;
padding: 0%;
margin: 0%;
min-height: 100vh; 
min-width: 100vw;
}

.Mid #TopLeft{
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
left: 16px;
font-family: Helvetica;
}
 .Mid #Selfie img{
display: block;
border-radius: 50%;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -400px;
margin-left: -100px;  
}

.Mid #TopRight {
position: absolute;
top: 3%;
right: 3%;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial,  sans-serif
}
 .Mid #About {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -200px;
   margin-left: -200px;
   text-align: center;
   max-width: 20%;

   }
```

Comment: Can you add a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) with working images? It will be easier to help you that way with code we can easily test and inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Ideally you should provide working examples with publicly available images, but I have recreated your example with a random image I found of a leaf.

The biggest problem I see is that you are going about your positioning all wrong. You're never going to get far with responsive design if you use absolute positioning for everything.

Instead you should start with using the natural flow of the document along with CSS techniques for adjusting the positioning. In this case it appears you are trying to have an image followed by a piece of text and you want both to be centred. There are a few techniques for centring in CSS. Here I have used the classic `margin: 0 auto` property to create automatically centred margins.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#topLeft {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#selfie img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:100px;
  width:auto;
}

#topRight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  right: 3%;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}

#about {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="topLeft">
    Daniel Apacik
  </div>
  <div id="selfie">
    <img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100758176/whitebeam-leaf-paul-sterry-NPL.jpg" alt="Example photo">
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto pariatur atque excepturi id vero voluptatibus iste commodi. Necessitatibus atque illo itaque officia exercitationem maiores culpa molestiae ipsa. Voluptates, iste magni.
  </div>
  <div id="topRight">
    Projects | Contact
  </div 
</body>
```

I'd suggest reading up on CSS techniques. A good start is CSS tricks. They have a pretty good guide on all things [centering with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) for example.

But as a general rule always avoid any positioning that assumes a width. Use relative positions with the ordering from your HTML, along with percentages, calc etc etc. When you do need to limit styles to a certain screen size, you can then use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for helping! :) I've tried learning CSS from FreeCodeCamp. However, I find it hard to recall all the rules and formats and the proper way to do things. Thanks again it helped a ton!

Comment: @Daniel.S.A great, if this was helpful to you/solved your issue please could you mark the question as correct and/or upvote it. StackOverflow operates on a reputation system and by doing that it will mean I will get reputation in recognition of my work.